# Only data from node 1 visible in a 2 node OrientDB cluster

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I created a 2-node OrientDB cluster by following the below steps. But while distributing it, the data present in only one of the node is accessible. Please can you help me debug this issue. The OrientDB version is 2.2.6

Steps involved :

- Utilized plocal mode in ETL tool and stored part of the data in node 1 and the other part in node2. The data stored actually belongs to just one class of vertex alone. ( On checking the data from console, the data has got injested properly ).
- Then executed both the nodes in distributed mode, data from only one machineis accessible.

The default-distributed-db-config.json file is specified below :

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 1,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
 "clusters": {
"internal": {

},
"address": {
  "servers" : [ "orientmaster" ]
},
"address_1": {
  "servers" : [ "orientslave1" ]
},
"*": {
  "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
}
  }
}
```

There are two clusters created for the vertex named address namely address and address_1. The data in machine orientslave1 is stored using ETL tool into cluster address_1 , similarly the data in machine orientmaster is stored into the cluster address. ( I've ensured that both of these cluster ids are different at time of creation )

However when these two machines are connected together in distributed mode, the data in cluster address_1 is only visible

The ETL json is attached below :

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/home/ubuntu/labvolume1/DataStorage/geo1_5lacs.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {"columnsOnFirstLine": false, "columns":["place:string"] } },
  "transformers": [
{ "vertex": { "class": "ADDRESS", "skipDuplicates":true } }
  ],
  "loader": {
"orientdb": {
   "dbURL": "plocal:/home/ubuntu/labvolume1/orientdb/databases/ETL_Test1",
   "dbType": "graph",
   "dbUser": "admin",
   "dbPassword": "admin",
   "dbAutoCreate": true,
   "wal": false,
   "tx":false,
   "classes": [
     {"name": "ADDRESS", "extends": "V", "clusters":1}
   ], "indexes": [

     {"class":"ADDRESS", "fields":["place:string"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
   ]

}
  }
}
```

Please let me know, if there is anything i'm doing wrongly

Comment: Do you have also the ETL file?

Comment: @Lvca, thanks for responding, I've attached the ETL file above.

Comment: @Lvca, just confirmed that the data is not deleted rather its not visible in distributed mode. When i started the individual servers separately, the data was visible.